# LIKE functionality for sentence in lucene

Tags: java, solr, lucene, lucene.net

I'm trying to replicate the LIKE functionality of SQL in Lucene.

If I search using the wildcards, say "*Tulips Inn Riyadhh*" I'm facing with the following behaviour:

1. Tulips Inn Riyadh - Matching
2. Tulips Inn Riyadhhhss - Not Matching
3. Tulips Inn Riyadh hhss - Matching
4. Tulips - matching
5. Riyadhh - matching

Actually i need an example in Lucene where condition "2" should match and "4" should not match.

I tried with all queries but second scenario is not matching.

Some people advised to use the Tokenizer and custom Analyser.

Since i'm new to Lucene I worked with queries, but doesn't know how to integrate Tokenizer and custom Analyser to our queries.

Comment: Adding in your post the analyzer chain of the fields involved in your search, all the parameters used in the queries you've tried and the version of Solr you're using would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you *only* want prefix matching, you can use a KeywordTokenizer with a LowercaseFilter and an EdgeNgramFilter:

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="50"/>
</analyzer>
```

This chain will keep the incoming text as a single token (KeywordTokenizer), then convert the incoming text to lowercase (LowerCaseFilter) before splitting it into multiple tokens based on string length.

If you want to match anywhere within a string, you can use a plain ngramfilter:

```
<filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="4"/>
```

.. but be aware that the size of your index will grow quickly if the difference between min and max is large.

There is a second option as well, and that's using the ReversedWildcardFilter which is specifically tuned for the `*foo*` query condition, so if you don't need further processing of each token (such as stemming each separate token, etc.) that might be an option.